# Using INSERT INTO with a variable amount of selected columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to use an `INSERT INTO SELECT` when the selected columns are coming from an Sql Parameter:

```
@selectedColumns varchar(1000),
@testInput1 varchar(100),
@testInput2 varchar(100)

Insert into Report
Select @selectedColumns
from Test
where @testInput1 = @testInput2;
```

I get the error: `Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition` because the values won't match up when generating the stored procedure.

The @selectedColumns input variable is being filled from a .NET MVC Controller with the columns in a comma separated string, like so:

```
"Column1, Column2, Column3"
```

So it would look like 1 column when you just look at the variable, but is actually anywhere from 1 to 10(the amount in the Report table). They all have a matching column in the report table.

Comment: Yes, but this is just a weird query to begin with.  And the error you're getting is unrelated to that.  Your error message is saying that the `Report` table's structure isn't matching that of your single column you're trying to insert.

Comment: `@selectedRows` is a comma separated list of rows that is dynamically created. Like `Column1, Column2, Column3`

Comment: In that case, you'll want to construct the query dynamically using that variable.  As written, you're literally selecting `"field1, field2, field3 ..."` as a single `VARCHAR (1000)` column.

Comment: when you say rows, you mean columns

Answer (score 0):

You can create store procedure and execute query like this

```
    create procedure insertdata(@selectedRows varchar(1000),
    @testInput1 varchar(100),
    @testInput2 varchar(100)
    }
   as
    begin
    Declare @query varchar(max)
    set @query='Insert into Report
    Select '+@selectedRows+
    'from Test where' +'@testInput1+' = '+@testInput2

    excute @query
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do this by using User Defined table type.